# From one nonexplosive markov chain to another

Tags: probability-theory

Fix a continuous time Markov Chain. (I am using Liggett's definition in Ch.2 which is that paths have to be right continuous with left limits and the state space is countable.  Everything else is canonical)  Let us suppose this chain is nonexplosive, which means that there is a Q matrix for which the minimal solution to the Kolmogorov backward equation is stochastic, and that minimal solution is the transition function for this MC (and hence no other up to the usual equivalence). (again, these ideas are also defined in Liggett's continuous-time Markov processes book)  Suppose that $\pi$ is a stationary measure for this setup, and that the MC is actually irreducible recurrent.  Then why do I know that the setup, which I describe with the following transition function, is nonexplosive, i.e. derived from a Q-matrix:

$p'_t(x, y)=\pi(y)*p_t(y, x)/\pi(x)$ ?

The obvious candidate for a Q matrix from which this could be derived as the minimal solution to the KBE is

$q(x, y)=\pi(y)/\pi(x)*q(y, x)$.

Trouble is that when I try to verify it's a Q matrix by checking that the row sum is 0, I run into the problem of not even knowing if the sum converges, let alone is value 0.  There's a fact that under some convergence condition (namely the summability of $\pi(x)(-q(x, x))$) one has that stationarity is equivalent to $0=\sum_{x \in S}(\pi(x)q(x, y))$.   Here the required condition is not met.  To see why I need this, see Liggett prop 2.61.

I am also interested in generalizing the equivalent condition for stationarity to other situations, but don't see how.  I would appreciate a workaround solution, but better yet to generalize this equivalence because I feel like I'm really missing something, since Liggett often does not prove convergence conditions are met as if it's trivial or something.